# What does it mean "The tangent line to the curve $y = f(x)$"

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My book says the following: "The tangent line to the curve $y = f(x)$ at the point $P(a,f(a))$ is the line through $P$ with slope"

I understand it except for when it says that "$y = f(x)$". I thought that it was assumed $f(x)$ always represents the y points. Why is it bothering mentioning it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book seems to be just being explicit that $y$ depends on $x$. Meaning, that $y$ is some function of $x$, $f(x)$. Some examples would be $y=2x+3$ or $y=\sin x$, where $f(x)=2x+3$ or $f(x)=\sin x$, respectively. Though yes, we could have just defined $f(x)=2x+3$ or $f(x)=\sin x$ and talked about the tangent line accordingly, without ever bringing $y$ into things.

As for the tangent line at a point. A *tangent line* to a function $f(x)$ at a point $(x,y)$ is just the line that goes through the point $(x,y)$ that has the same slope as $f(x)$ at that point.